# What do symbols such as $C^{1+\epsilon},\,C^{2+\epsilon},\,C^{2-\epsilon}$ mean?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, dynamical-systems

I am reading *Stochastic Dynamics of Deterministic Systems* by M. Viana. These symbols appear when he talks about expanding maps on compact connected manifolds. Can someone answer what do these symbols mean? Moreover, can someone answer what are the definitions of $C^1$-topology and $C^{1+\epsilon}$-topology?

Comment: (Without looking at the context, so take it with a grain of salt) I think $C^{k+\epsilon}$ means that the function is $k$ times differentiable and the $k$-th derivative is $\epsilon$-Holder continuous. The topology would be given by the maximum of the suprema of first $k$ derivatives and the appropriate Holder norm. No idea about $C^{k-\epsilon}$

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Maybe $C^{k-\epsilon}=C^{(k-1)+1-\epsilon}$. From the book the condition $||Df(x)\cdot v||\geq\sigma ||v||$ for all $x\in M$ and $v\in T_x M$, where $f:M\rightarrow M$ and $\sigma>1$, is a $C^1$ open condition on the map. Do you know the meaning of this

Comment: It means that the set of $f$ such that this is true is open in the $C^1$ topology, meaning that for any $f$ satisfying it, if you take any $g$ such that $f,g$ and $f', g'$ are sufficiently close in the supremum norm, then $g$ also satisfies it.